# localhost/PHPMyAdmin wants an Account

Tags: php, mysql, phpmyadmin, wampserver

I just set up my WampServer and wanted to go to phpMyAdmin only to get a login screen. So I try to login in with my MySQL credentials. Didnt work. I have no idea how to fix this and nobody ever seemed to have that problem. [Here is a screen shot of the site](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AwPjZ.png)

Comment: Try with username: `root` and a empty password

Comment: please try username: root and password : root

Comment: Thanks. Now I feel really fcking stupid